# CakePHP Query with Result Rank

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to get the "rank" of a record in my CakePHP application and I am having trouble doing it on the database end.  I know I can use an example like this to get the item rank with a SQL query...

```
SET @rownum := 0;
SELECT rank, id FROM (
        SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, id
        FROM item_table ORDER BY some_count DESC
        ) as result WHERE id=xxxxxxxx
```

I originally tried to use the model query function to perform this task, but CakePHP throws errors when I try to use a multi-statement query.

```
$rank = $this->Item->query("SET @rownum := 0; SELECT rank, id FROM (SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, id FROM item_table ORDER BY some_count DESC ) as result WHERE id=xxxxxxxx");
```

This seems to be a more efficient approach than what I am currently doing in CakePHP, which is getting a list of all the records ordered by "some_count" and then looping through them until I have the result. My table could grow to millions of records, so this would become very strenuous very quickly on the application server.

```
$itemList = $this->Item->find(
        'list',
        array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Item.hidden' => 0
            ),
            'order' => array(
                'Item.some_count DESC',
                'Item.created DESC'
            ),
            'fields' => array(
                'Item.id'
            )
        )
    );

    $rank;
    $i = 1;
    foreach($itemList as $j){
        if($j == $currItem['Item']['id']){
            $rank = $i;
            break;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $this->set('itemRank', $rank);
```

Is there a way to efficiently get the "rank" of a record in CakePHP?  I'm looking for something other than a "brute force" solution, which is what I have now. The item's rank will change very frequently based on how it performs against the other records in the table, so it's not something I could actively store in the table as it would probably need to be calculated every second, or even fraction of a second.

Comment: How are you calculating the "rank"?

Comment: Rank is the row "index" in the order by statement. Based on the eample I have given, the row with the highest "some_count" would be 0, since some_count is ordered by DESC.  The records are ordered by the query, but there is no index of that order without either finding it via the loop in my example or returning the rank as a MySQL variable in the MySQL query.

Comment: Still kind of lost - so "rank" is a field in your table?  Or is it a calculation based on multiple fields in your table?

Comment: Rank is simply where the row exists in the order by statement. The query returns all of the rows from the table in a certain order based on "some_count" and "created", but there is no index that indicates where that row is in the array. To find its index, I either have to loop through the array within cake, as in my example, but a more efficient way to do it would be in MySQL, again in my example, but there doesn't appear to be a way to perform that query with CakePHP.

Comment: Gotcha.  I guess the next question is - how do you want to use the rank?  For example - paginating the results, and listing it's "rank" to the left of it, then, when you click, showing it's "rank" on it's details page? Or... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be you could use this.

```
        SELECT id, some_count, FIND_IN_SET(
                                     some_count
                                ,  (SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(
                                    DISTINCT some_count
                                    ORDER BY some_count  DESC
                                 )
                             FROM    item_table)
                           ) as rank
        FROM  item_table;
```

With cakephp query() function.

see [mysql rank trip](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2009/09/mysql-another-ranking-trick.html) for more info. :)

Comment: Perfect.  By passing a where clause so that I find by ID, then the record and its rank are retrieved; I get exactly what I needed.  Thank you much!